# Add to ManyToMany Ahead of Time

Tags: django, django-models

Supposing I have a model in Django with a manytomany field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    m2m_field = models.ManyToMany(OtherModel)

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    some_text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

If I list MyModel's attributes, there is no m2m_field until I save it.

```
>>> my_model.m2m_field
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 897, in __get__
    through=self.field.rel.through,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 586, in __init__
(instance, source_field_name))
ValueError: "<MyModel>" needs to have a value for field "mymodel" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Okay, fair enough. So I call `my_model.save()`, and then I get a `RelatedManager` object on `my_model.m2m_field` and I can call `my_model.m2m_field.add(other_model_instance)`.

But.... is there any way to do this in advance? Sometimes it's not so great to post something without certain fields.

Comment: What do you mean "do this in advance"? You always have to save the model before adding many to many fields.

Comment: Either put mymodel below othermodel or add quotes around the reference

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure about your question but I *think* you want to look into post save on the dependent object:

http://www.djangofoo.com/tag/post_save

The idea being that you can save an OtherModel automagically whenever a MyModel is saved?

Feel free to clarify if I have missed your point.